# Large (huge) array creating in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception, large-data

I am fighting with problem of a large array. I need to read lots of csv files and work with them (make tables and save them). I try it this way

```
String[,,] pole = new string[5000, 10251, 100];
...

String[] proz = File.ReadAllText("@/../../History/201" + r + "-" + m1 + m2 + "-" + d1 + d2 + "_00/variables_ens.csv").Split(';');

            for (int k = 0; k < 10251; k++)
            {

                int l = k / 99;
                int lk = l * 99;
                int b = k - lk;
                pole[n, l, b] = proz[k];
            }
```

But in the first row

```
String[,,] pole = new string[5000, 10251, 100];
```

It says out of range exception, but i do need that much space. When i write

```
String[,,] pole = new string[100, 10251, 100];
```

It works, but only for the hundred of those files.
Any suggestion, please?

Comment: You could use a List<> instead of an array its more flexible. You should need it not every CSV has the same amount of content. So the list can grow and has no hard coded indexe range.

Comment: well if what you said is the case as in "IndexOutOfRangeException", that's not size problem that's you accessing a non-existant element, hence you should use a dynamic data structure, maybe List

Comment: Rebuild your project as x64, then try again. If this does not work, get more memory.

Comment: Where is the `n` variable coming from? It doesn't appear anywhere in your code until you try to use it to index into your array. Since changing the first dimension of the array makes the error go away, there's a good chance that the way you're using `n` is the root of the problem, and you've given us no information about that.

Comment: Also be aware that an array with the dimensions 5000, 10251, 100 would take up 20 GB in memory _when it is completely empty_. I think you need to come up with a better strategy for approaching this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you need to rethink your whole strategy and implement streaming vie `IEnumerable<T>` and [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) .

I don't have enough elements to understand completely what you're trying to achieve with you current implementation, but I'm pretty sure that the size of the data you're trying to manipulate is too much to be processed in memory.

What do you need to do? What data are you manipulating? 5000 files of 1025100 lines each? Every file has the same size? Do you REALLY, REALLY need to load everything at once?

The answers on this question should point you in the right direction. I would say you need to use streaming to efficiently load the data in some more manageable form (like a database).

Answer (score 2):

In your statement you declare an array of 5000 * 10251 * 100 elements. This is 5,125,500,000 elements which is a number that is out of range for memory allocation in a single block(at least in 32 bit systems). You can either split your data to 2 or 3 different arrays or use a dynamic allocation structure like a List<>.